# using python to calculate Vector Projection

Tags: python, numpy

Is there an easier command to compute vector projection?
I am instead using the following:

```
x = np.array([ 3, -4,  0])
y = np.array([10,  5, -6])
z=float(np.dot(x, y))
z1=float(np.dot(x, x))
z2=np.sqrt(z1)
z3=(z/z2**2)
x*z3
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Maybe this is what you really want:

```
np.dot(x, y) / np.linalg.norm(y)
```

This should give the projection of vector `x` onto vector `y` - see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_projection. Alternatively, if you want to compute the projection of `y` onto `x`, then replace `y` with `x` in the denominator (`norm`) of the above equation.

EDIT: As @VaidAbhishek commented, the above formula is for the *scalar* projection. To obtain *vector* projection multiply scalar projection by a unit vector in the direction of the vector onto which the first vector is projected. The formula then can be modified as:

```
y * np.dot(x, y) / np.dot(y, y)
```

for the vector projection of `x` onto `y`.

Comment: This is scalar projection. To get vector projection, you need to multiply this (Scalar) with a unit vector in direction of y.

Comment: @VaidAbhishek Thank you! You are correct. I have edited my answer.

Answer (score 6):

The projection of **a** onto **b** is defined as

[image]

So either

`(np.dot(a, b) / np.dot(b, b)) * b`

or

`(np.dot(a, b) / np.linalg.norm(b)**2 ) * b`