# Not getting direction value in my velocity calculation

Tags: python, skyfield

I am working on a ground station to track our future cubesat, one of the things needed is to calculate the doppler shift in the frequency as it passes over head. To test this we are using the ISS TLE. I am using Skyfield and it has been super helpful, but I am having a simple issue that I can't seem to figure out. I need the velocity of the object, which has been easily attained, but I also need the direction relative to my position. I assumed it would be part of the velocity vector, since velocity is both magnitude and direction. Maybe I'm missing something in the code that is obvious, the way it is fixed at the moment is to get the distance at two points in time and figure out if its closing in or distancing itself. Then I simply multiply the vector by -1 if its closing in, and 1 otherwise. I figured something like this would be handled with the .velocity function but it does not seem so.

```
diff = satObsDiff.at(ts_now)
diff1 = satObsDiff.at(ts_next)

velocity = diff.speed().km_per_s * 1000 #converts km to m
print("Velocity: ")
print(velocity)
adjusted_velocity = velocity

range1 = diff.distance().km
range2 = diff1.distance().km
change = (range1 - range2)*1000

direction = 1

if change >= 0:
    direction = 1
else:
    direction = -1

observed_freq = ((C/(C + (adjusted_velocity * direction))) * emitted_freq)
```

Answer (score 1):

The dot product of two vectors is positive if they are pointing in the same direction, zero if they are at right angles, and negative if they are pointing away from each other. So I suspect you can tell an approaching from a receding satellite by computing the dot product of the relative position with the velocity and checking whether it is more or less than zero:

```
d = np.dot(velocity.km, diff.position.km)
if d > 0:
   print('receding')
else:
   print('approaching')
```

You can also toss in some division if you want to know how fast the range is changing:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/55226228/85360